# Subordinate clauses: Use of "in case" to replace inside a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clauses

I have this sentence I'm struggling with, it's from the "subordinate clauses" subject:
*You should never sleep on a mattress that is too hard. It can give you back pain.*

I have to use "in case" inside the sentence, but I don't know if my tries are correct:

Try 1: *In case you sleep on a mattress that is too hard, it can give you back pain.*

Try 2: *You should never sleep on a mattress that is too hard in case it gives you back pain.*

My mother language is Spanish, but I get along with English pretty well.

Comment: Neither of these sentences is using **in case** idiomatically. *Take your umbrella in case it rains.* **in case** introduces a clause that expresses something which *could* happen, a real possibility, but not  an actuality.  *In case they ask you to sleep on the floor, be aware, sleeping on a floor can make you sore.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I found the same problem there, it doesn't really sound right because I know the consequence, but although it's not right, is there any sentence that could be less-wrong? The exercise is from the book Life by National Geographic Learning

Comment: I think they're going for something like this: *You should never eat an unidentified mushroom in case it is poisonous.* To my ear, that's still marginal.  *Let's not eat that mushroom in case it's poisonous.* would be idiomatic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Actually, I find #2 reasonably idiomatic.  It certainly fits "a real possibility, but not an actuality".

Comment: @stangdon: By "reasonably idiomatic" do you  mean "less than perfectly idiomatic"?

Comment: BrE here, *in case it gives you back pain* is actually common, but seems to be a contraction / corruption of *in [the] case [that] it gives you pain, [you should...]*. In modern English it *is* "idiomatic", in any case. It's taken over from *lest*.

Comment: To qualify that: “better grammar” would be, e.g. *Take care when you sleep on a hard mattress, …*.

Comment: To set the record straight, I agree that #2 is not very nice grammar …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should not jump out of an airplane without a parachute, **in case
>   you plummet to your death**. <sup>not idiomatic</sup>
>
> You should not jump out of an airplane without a parachute, **lest you
>   plummet to your death**. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> You should not jump out of an airplane without a parachute, **because you
>   would plummet to your death**. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> Take a parachute **in case you have to jump out of the airplane**. The airplane looks as though a mechanic has not touched it in 50 years. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> Take a tire repair kit with you **in case you get a flat on your bike trip.**

Comment: So the least wrong solution would be to use an imperative sentence to be able to insert in case?
_Don't sleep on a mattress that is too hard in case it gives you back pain_

Comment: "least unidiomatic", OK. **in case** is used with specific potential situations or outcomes, not generalizations.  *Never play with a snake in case it's poisonous.* sounds really odd to my ear.  *Let's steer clear of that snake, in case it's poisonous.* sounds fine. The main clause also has an affirmative-spin.  *Always steer clear of snakes in case they're poisonous.* OK.

Comment: *Don't walk out on the ice in case it's too thin!*  is something many a native speaker could easily say.  But it's marginal to my ear, because of the negative polarity. *Stay off the ice in case it's too thin!* sounds much better.

Comment: The first example can easily be made "more correct" by rephrasing as *Wear a parachute when flying, **in case** it falls from the air*. But the meaning *has* drifted: your final snake example is idiomatic even though it seems rather “ungrammatical” to me.

Comment: @Will Crawford: What does **it** refer to in your parachute senence?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo good catch! :o) ... It's too late to edit, but that should read *in case **the plane** falls from the air*.